# How to update an offline Debian 7 to Debian 8

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade

I have an offline Debian 7 server, which I would like to update to Debian 8 at some stage, but I fear I'll do it wrong, so here I go ask you first for best practice to go about this. 
Currently the maintenance and normal debian updates are done with `apt-offline`.

- Can I use the same utility for upgrading to Debian 8?
- If yes, how exactly? Change the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file to `jessie` fist and then create a new signature for apt-offline?
- Might using `apt-cdrom` be an alternative for the initial upgrade from 7 to 8 and then `apt-offline` after that?

Comment: Why can you not do a normal online update? An offline update has extra risks. Would it be better to online, update, offline?

You could try using apt-offline should work to update, if that's what you need. The upgrade process shouldn't be any different then normal.  update, change sources, upgrade, update. But those steps need to be done individually. update -> signature -> download -> install -> change sources -> signature -> download -> install etc.

Comment: unfortunately online is no option. sometimes machines are just too remote, so there is just no internet available, sometimes it's just the company policy that prohibits the machine from being connected to an online network, even if it sounds stupid... I gotta go with it, so apt-offline has worked quite well so far. But I was wondering if it is really the best option for a full debian version upgrade. Thanks for pointing out the order of things I would need to do... Maybe you like to make that an answer.